# HttpClient behaviour in multithreading and concurrent context

Tags: java, http, httpclient

Can anyone help me to clarify how `HttpClient` behaves in multithreading?

When I create `HttpClient` object via the code below, should I keep the object globally across the app life cycle (this method is suggested in `HttpClient` doc), or should I create every time when I want to perform Http connection (Get and Post)?

```
1)
Static HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //so we can use this object in everywhere.

2) 
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //do this every time when we want to establish http connect.
```

What is the best way to make sure the Http connections will not block each other and to make sure they can run concurrently?

Comment: My suggestion is 2nd one because if you use static variable concurrent access of object may throw exception or unexpected results. In Jmeter(performance/load testing tool) they are creating different objects for different threads. But If number of threads are small and threads are only doing read only then you can use static variable with synchronized methods. Please correct me if I'm saying wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PoolingConnectionManager and configure how many connections per route you need (make sure you have as many connections as you have threads using them). Then you can simply inject the same httpclient everywhere. I've been using it like this for several years.

Also consider using ResponseHandlers everywhere; this vastly simplifies releasing of resources and connections.

Comment: Hi, if the connection pool has 3 connections. but my app will need 4 connection at the same time. how is the extra one been handled by `HttpClient`? Will `HttpClient` create one temporary connection or the extra one will have to wait/hang until the pool has idle connection?

Comment: Erm.. what does it means "per route"? does it means "per app life cycle"?

Comment: Network route. Basically, for the same route you can reuse connections. The connection pool tries to reuse open connections to the server after they are released by httpclient. That's why the pooling connection manager is nice to have. Basically you configure the maximum amount of connections you want it to hand out. If you exceed that number, threads are going to end up waiting for a connection to be released. You can set a timeout for that as well and you will start seeing timeouts. Typically you want to have as many connections as you have threads.